# Отправка GET-запроса через определенное время

Tags: jquery, javascript

Всем привет.
Напишите, пожалуйста, пример, как посылать GET-запросы с помощью JQ через определенное время - 1 раз в 10 секунд.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Все гениальное просто.

```
setInterval(функция, интервал в миллисекундах);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function pushget() {
xmlhttp.open("GET","demo_get2.php?fname=Иван&lname=Петров",true);
xmlhttp.send();
  }
 myTimer = setInterval(pushget,100);
```

Что-то типо такого, наверное.

Answer (score 2):

Ни один из ответов не учитывает той особенности, что ГЕТ-запрос не обязан приходить мгновенно. В случае проблем с сетью использование сетИнтервал будет создавать клубок запросов, которые будут вносить хаос в происходящее.
Для опросов на коротких интервалах нужно использовать setTimeout:

```
var url = "http://example.com", 
    data = {}; 
sendGetQuery();

function sendGetQuery() {
    $.ajax(url, data).done(function(){
        setTimeout(sendGetQuery, 10000);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вариантов на самом деле очень много. Можно и с jQuery.

```
 setInterval(function(){
        $.get("test.php", { name: "Rohan", time: "2pm" } );
    }, 10000)
```

Есть еще $.ajax с type:'get'

Comment: Ну, формально `$.get` - это просто алиас `$.ajax({type: 'get',... })`

Comment: Мало ли что человеку по душе.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно, чтобы запросы выполнялись через равные промежутки времени, и известно, что они наверняка больше выполнения самих запросов, то через setInterval:

```
function myGet() {
    // код
}
setInterval(myGet, 30000); // раз в 30 секунд
```

Если запросы могут выполняться долго, либо известно, что в условиях сети они могут выполняться долго, то лучше setTimeout:

```
function myTimer() {
    myGet();
    setTimeout(myTimer, 30000);
}
myTimer();
```

В первом случае каждый запрос выполняется независимо от того, успел ли отработать предыдущий, а во втором каждый следующий выполнится через заданный интервал после выполнения предшествующего. Если запросы выполняют асинхронно, то во втором случает новый setTimeout следует вызывать в callback:

```
function myGet() {
    $.get(
        url,
        { param: value },
        function (data) {
            // обработка результата запроса
            setTimeout(myGet, 30000);
        }
    )
}
myGet();
```